# Unable to host in heroku due to excessive errors

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have been trying to host in Heroku for the last week and can't figure out the problem I am facing!
The app is deployed and built successfully but when I open the URL it says "Application Error"

Then when I run `heroku logs` I was given with this...

```
2020-08-21T16:21:04.049609+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2020-08-21T16:21:04.049638+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2020-08-21T16:21:04.136860+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-08-21T16:21:04.175715+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2020-08-21T16:21:11.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-08-21T16:25:25.745203+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=kti-bylimra.herokuapp.com request_id=920d0650-de28-4b2f-928d-6a97a46fc0db fwd="112.135.197.200" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2020-08-21T16:25:27.248826+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=kti-bylimra.herokuapp.com request_id=3be3c388-44d4-4481-891a-4ccc8ed79c85 fwd="112.135.197.200" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2020-08-21T16:25:37.977206+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=kti-bylimra.herokuapp.com request_id=b8ea34c4-2625-47c2-842f-256d727e48de fwd="112.135.197.200" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2020-08-21T16:25:38.166373+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=kti-bylimra.herokuapp.com request_id=f095f479-6ec5-4f22-ac97-0d3e499ebc2c fwd="112.135.197.200" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2020-08-21T16:25:38.926833+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=kti-bylimra.herokuapp.com request_id=99979365-e018-47f7-9167-2594b7c3eaa9 fwd="112.135.197.200" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2020-08-21T16:26:00.656226+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate` by user najaaznabhan@gmail.com
2020-08-21T16:26:12.645457+00:00 heroku[run.1617]: State changed from starting to up
2020-08-21T16:26:12.745856+00:00 heroku[run.1617]: Awaiting client
2020-08-21T16:26:12.766309+00:00 heroku[run.1617]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate`
2020-08-21T16:26:17.526815+00:00 heroku[run.1617]: Process exited with status 1
2020-08-21T16:26:17.559197+00:00 heroku[run.1617]: State changed from up to complete
```

I then tried running `heroku run rails console` as someone else recommended but I was thrown with this error!

```
bash: rails: command not found
```

I wondered whether something was wrong with my Procfile but I could not find any flaws. The name of my app is kti and inside that directory where the settings.py is also included was the wsgi.py

```
web: gunicorn kti.wsgi
```

Even when I tried to run `heroku run python manage.py migrate` it had acted unexpectedly as it threw me this error.

```
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_cleanup/cache.py", line 107, in get_dotted_path
    return DOTTED_PATH.format(klass=object_.__class__)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 224, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 364, in _setup
    self._wrapped = get_storage_class()()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 359, in get_storage_class
    return import_string(import_path or settings.DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto3.py", line 17, in <module>
    from django.utils.six import BytesIO
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.utils.six'
```

I tried updating all modules including six, django-storages and backends..

Just in case here is my settings.py...

```
import django_heroku 
import os
.
.
.
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

As requested my django-heroku version is 0.3.1 and heroku version is 0.1.4. My version of django is 3.0.8.

Any help is greatly appreciated!
thanks!

Comment: What is the heroku django version ? and do you use corsheader ?

Comment: @EricMartin I have added the necessary versions in the bottom of the question. Hope you could help me, cuz I am in a bit of a desperate situation right now. Thanks!

Comment: @EricMartini forgot to mention that I don't use Corsheader, or at least I think I don't cuz I have no clue on what that is.

Comment: Django.utils.six has been removed in django 3.0 so you have two options : upgrade django-storages but you say you have already try. What your actual version? I personally use the 1.9.1 and everything is fine

Comment: Second option : downgrade django to 2.9

Comment: @EricMartin OMG dude you are a legend. Thanks a lot for the help. When I tried upgrading to the latest version of django-storages, it didn't happen and kept me on, 1.7.1. I manually upgraded it and it works perfectly fine

Comment: I can't thank you more dudeee. I really appreciate your effort

Comment: i'am glad this helped. I post the answer, can you accept it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django.utils.six has been removed in django 3.0

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/3.0/#removed-private-python-2-compatibility-apis

so you have two options :

1. Upgrade django-storages  version >= 1.8
   see release note :
   https://pypi.org/project/django-storages/1.8/
2. Downgrade django to version < 3.0